# How do I check that composer package installed in bash script

Tags: php, bash, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer package if it not installed in bash script. But now it doesn't work, and `no_package` function always pass

```
#!/bin/bash -e

no_package() {
    composer show | grep matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch | test
}

if [ no_package ]; then
  composer require "matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch"
else
  echo 'Package installed'
fi
```

UPD: Here is solution

```
package_installed() {
    composer show | grep matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch --quiet
}
if package_installed; then
  echo 'Package installed'
else
  composer require "matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two misunderstandings here:

1. You can't pipe stuff to `test`.
2. `if some_command` is the way to do something if a command succeeds. `[ no_package ]` doesn't actually run the command, it simply checks that the string "no_package" is not empty and therefore always succeeds.

In addition to this you may want to use the `--quiet` flag to `grep` to avoid printing the package name.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the `test` command, and I found that the `test` command returned the same result no matter what I piped in.

So it is better to run in this way

```
package_exist() {
    composer show | grep matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch >/dev/null
}

if package_exist; then
    echo 'installed'
else
    echo 'uninstalled'
    echo 'installing matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch'
    composer require "matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch"
fi
```